# Oracle SQL fetch rows with more than one action per employee

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query

```
select xx.* from (SELECT DISTINCT
        papf.person_id,
        papf.person_number                      ,
        ppnf.display_name                       ,
        pgft.name  grade                        ,
        pjft.name  job                          ,
        hapft.name position                     ,
        national_identifier_number "national id",
        to_char(papf.start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') "Hire Date",
        case when paaf.assignment_status_type ='ACTIVE' then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end   Status,
       to_char(paaf.effective_start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') "Effective Period2",
       pat.action_name Action       
        
FROM
                                                                                             
        per_all_people_f papf
        
        LEFT JOIN per_person_names_f ppnf ON         ppnf.person_id        = papf.person_id
        AND     ppnf.name_type = 'GLOBAL'
        AND     SYSDATE BETWEEN ppnf.effective_start_date AND     ppnf.effective_end_date
        
        LEFT JOIN per_all_assignments_m paaf ON paaf.person_id = papf.person_id
                AND paaf.assignment_type = 'E'

        LEFT JOIN       HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F_TL hapft on hapft.position_id = paaf.position_id
        AND hapft.language    = 'US'
        
        LEFT JOIN       per_jobs_f_tl pjft ON pjft.job_id   = paaf.job_id
        AND     pjft.language = 'US'


        LEFT JOIN       per_grades_f_tl pgft ON      pgft.grade_id = paaf.grade_id
        AND     pgft.language = 'US'

        LEFT JOIN       PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS pna ON pna.person_id            = papf.person_id
        
        LEFT JOIN PER_ACTION_OCCURRENCES pao ON pao.action_occurrence_id = paaf.action_occurrence_id 
        
        
        LEFT JOIN PER_ACTIONS_TL pat ON pat.action_id = pao.action_id 
        and pat.language = 'US'
        
        group by  
        papf.person_number,
        papf.person_id,
        ppnf.display_name,
        pgft.name,
        pjft.name,
        hapft.name,
        national_identifier_number,
        to_char(papf.start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'),
       to_char(paaf.effective_start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'),
       pat.action_name,
       paaf.assignment_status_type
       
       HAVING COUNT(person_number)>1

)XX
where XX.person_id IN
(NVL (:Emps, XX.person_id)) 
 and (XX.Status in :P_status or :P_status is null)
ORDER BY XX.person_number
```

**sample data**:

| employee_number | action_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hire |
| 2 | hire |
| 2 | promotion |
| 7 | hire |

I want to fetch rows where employees have more than an action, in this case employee with number `2`, how can I do that ?

I tried to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` but it return empty results, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: There are multiple tables within the query, and a dataset(named "sample data) which is not known how could be returned ..

Comment: i edited the query and put the original one, but its the same result with additional columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` expression along with `HAVING` keyword, in which the number of employees counted such as

```
SELECT emp.employee_number
  FROM employees emp
  LEFT JOIN assignments assgn
    ON assgn.emp_id = emp.emp_id
 GROUP BY emp.employee_number
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Alternatively use an analytic aggregation

```
SELECT employee_number, action_type
  FROM
  ( SELECT emp.employee_number, assgn.action_type,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY emp.employee_number) AS cnt
      FROM employees emp
      LEFT JOIN assignments assgn
        ON assgn.emp_id = emp.emp_id )
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

in order to bring whole columns per each row.

Comment: it returns empty result, i will put the original query, can you plz check it